# Maximum size of std::size and std::map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, set

What is maximum size of std::size and std::map? And is there a way to increase this number?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with maximum size of `std::size`??

Comment: [std::map::max_size](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/max_size/) returns the max size your map can hold.

Comment: The real limitation is probably system resources, notably RAM, swap space....

Comment: This will depend on your underlying OS and the the limitations of allocating memory on the heap IMHO.

Comment: `std::map::max_size()` will return a size that the map is guaranteed **not** to exceed. However, it will usually not even get close to this size, and [the function is considered not very useful](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3440.html#197).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get maximum size of every standard library container by calling [`Container::max_size()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/max_size) on it. If you need theoretical maximum size value at compile time, use `std::numeric_limits<Container::size_type>::max()`.

Comment: Just because in some implementation of some container `max_size()` happens to return `std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max()` does not in any way imply that the user can use `std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max()` directly to determine the maximum size of the container.

Comment: Moreover, the text at your link makes no sense whatsoever. `max_size()` must return the size in terms of number of *elements*, while `std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max()` returns the *range* of the type. These quantities have different dimensions.

Comment: @AndreyT, what? `max_size()` returns `size_type`; `numeric_limits<size_type>::max()` returns `constexpr size_type`. I think both are the same type, therefore both are **numbers** representing the same idea - but one taking runtime environment into consideration, and one being resolved at compile time.

Comment: For example, `std::vector` typically uses `std::size_t` as it `size_type`. However, if I declare a vector that has elements that occupy 64K each, I should expect the theoretical limit of max size to be equal `std::numeric_limits<vector::size_type>::max() / 65536`. Note: range divided by `65536`. In such case using `std::numeric_limits<vector::size_type>::max()` by itself, without dividing it by element size makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: @AndreyT, what? `size_type` is used to express **number** of elements, not their total **size** in bytes. That's a **huge** misconception.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm talking about. However, `std::numeric_limits` does not know and does not care what the type is "used" for. `std::numeric_limits` does not care about any "bytes" or "elements". It just gives you the full range of the type. And the point is that the full range of `container::size_type` has absolutely no connection to the maximum number of elements, as illustrated by my `std::vector` example.

Comment: Just try it yourself: declare `std::vector`s with different element sizes and compare `max_size()` and `numeric_limits<size_type>::max()` to see that you will get completely different values. The relationship between these values is as I described above.

Comment: @AndreyT, you are currently talking bullshit. Of course it doesn't; that's why I (and the link) said that it's *theoretical*, and compile time (for use in magical thing called *templates*), as opposed to runtime and environment-aware `max_size()`. Again: compare **theoretical** and **compile time** values with **practical**, **runtime** ones. G'night.

Comment: I think all @AndreyT is saying is that the *theoretical* maximum size should be `std::numeric_limits<Container::size_type>::max() / sizeof(Container::value_type)`. [This](http://liveworkspace.org/code/286c4bacf373e32a7f374c35ed328fe7) seems to support his claim.

Comment: @Praetorian: Yes, but again, for obvious reasons this applies only to the continuous memory containers, of which `std::vector` is the only known example. For non-continuous memory containers (`std::map`, `std::list` etc) the `max_size()` might theoretically return `std::numeric_limits<Container::size_type>::max()`. None of this, of course, implies any inherent relationship between `std::numeric_limits<Container::size_type>::max()` and `max_size()`. It is just an implementation detail, which our easily excitable friend mistook for a part of specification.

Comment: @Praetorian: But if `container::max_size` happens to be a type that covers the entire range of the platform's memory addresses, then, of course, you can say that for absolutely any container you need to divide the range of `size_type` by container element size to obtain the theoretical limit on maximum element count (i.e. you can't just allocate more memory than you have addresses).

Comment: @AndreyT Yes, thank you, that's what I was trying to say also. There's no such requirement, but `size_t` usually does span the entire available address range, and so `max_size` will have to take size of the element into account.

Comment: I don't understand what is the debate about. `std::numeric_limits<Container::size_type>::max()` is an upper bound on the container size. So is `Container::max_size()` which is also an upper bound on the container size. The later is a *tighter* upper bound and thus is more useful. Anyway, there is no guarantee that one actually can create a container of this size, and the only use case for `max_size` I can think of is to do sanity checks for input values.

Comment: @ybungalobill: The debate is about what makes a useful answer to the original question and what doesn't. One can also say that `2^123456789` is also a [very loose] upper limit on the container size. Is it? Certainly yes. But does it make a useful (or even meaningful) answer to the original question? I strongly believe it doesn't.

Comment: @AndreyT: then I would say that the only useful answer is that "there is no way to know the maximum size of a container because they are practically limited by the amount of resources available at runtime, therefore one should write exception safe code and rely on `bad_alloc` being thrown".

Answer (score 3):

Maximum size of any standard container is given by `container<T>::max_size()` method. In general case, this size might (and will) be smaller than the range of `container<T>::size_type`.

The range of `container::size_type` can be obtained through `std::numeric_limits`, but, again, keep in mind that containers do not guarantee that their maximum size can reach the full range of their `size_type`.

Note also that `container<T>::max_size()` returns the maximum number of *elements* in the container, while `std::numeric_limits<container<T>::size_type>::max()` returns the *range* of the `size_type`. These are incomparable values.

Comment: This is in contradiction with the accepted answer, can you back it up with some reference?

Comment: @tobi303: Firstly, I don't see the contradiction. Secondly, the specification of `max_size()` in the standard is my reference. Thirdly, you can also try it in any compiler to see what `max_size()` normally does. For `std::vector<T>` you will typically see `std::numeric_limits<std::vector<T>::size_type>::max() / sizeof(T)`. This is not necessarily reachable, but the idea is clear.

Comment: ah ok i misread the other answer, it says "theoretical max size is `std::numeric_limits<Container::size_type>::max()`" but the actual max size can be smaller

Comment: @tobi303: Yes. Also `max_size()` is not required to be precise either. For example, `std::vector<T>::max_size()` in GCC returns `std::numeric_limits<std::vector<T>::size_type>::max() / sizeof(T)` . However, even that is not reachable, since GCC refuses to allocate memory blocks of size `SIZE_MAX`. It can only allocate up to `SIZE_MAX / 2`, which means that the *actual* maximum size of `std::vector<T>` is about 2 times smaller than `max_size()` reports.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretical limit is maximal number that `size_t` could contain which is typically used to return number of elements in container. For most 32 bit platforms its 2^32, for most 64 bit platforms its 2^64, but actually this is implementation defined, there are no strong restrictions in standard.

But practically the possible maximal size of any container is much less because it is limited by available memory address space and by available free memory.

Comment: Needed to say that usually on 32bit platforms you get `bac_alloc` after allocating ~3GB of memory.