# How to solve bad allocation exception c++

Tags: c++

I am inserting the data into a map variable,

```
map<std::pair<uint32_t, uint32_t>, double>& myMapData
```

when the size of this variable goes around 21589169 am getting the error message "bad allocation"

`myMapData.max_size()` is 268435455.

How I can solve this issue?

Comment: try not to allocate this amount of data to std::map, we're talking about 20 megabyte of data here. think about serialize your data into external file and work upon it

Comment: Thts a huge data to store in variable. Never came across such situations. Please use a database to store data.

Comment: This data is coming from a device, I have to process and pass it to generate some graph. So, is there a way to avoid this error on inserting data to this map variable?

Comment: That's much more than 20 MB (16 bytes + two pointers + some more per element) but it should be way less than a GB. On a normal desktop machine this shouldn't be a problem, unless you're copying the map a lot, or using huge amounts of memory elsewhere. The reference looks suspicious - is it possible that the object this variable refers to has become invalid?

Comment: Please add the code you using when calling your function, which var are passed to the function by ref?

Comment: You should print myMapData.max_size(). It is not the same as the theoretical maximum size. ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054163/maximum-size-of-stdsize-and-stdmap)) 
I've tried it with gcc, and it was 134217727. Perhaps an other stl implementation or an other compiler will return different result.

Comment: myMapData max size is 268435455